# Scala hash of stacks has only one stack for all the keys

Tags: scala

I have the following hashmap, where each element should be mapped to a stack:

```
var pos = new HashMap[Int, Stack[Int]] withDefaultValue Stack.empty[Int]           
 for(i <- a.length - 1 to 0 by -1) {
            pos(a(i)).push(i)
}
```

If `a` will have elements `{4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6}`,
and if I add the following lines after the code above:

```
println("pos(0) is " + pos(0))
println("pos(4) is " + pos(4))
```

The output will be:

```
pos(0) is Stack(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
pos(4) is Stack(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Why is this happening?
I don't want to add elements to `pos(0)`, but only to `pos(4)` and `pos(6)` (the lements of `a`).

It looks like there is only one stack mapped to all the keys. I want a stack for each key.

Answer (score 3):

Check the docs:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

method `withDefaultValue` takes this value as a regular parameter, it won't be recalculated so all your entries share the same mutable stack.

```
def withDefaultValue(d: B): Map[A, B]
```

<del>You should use `withDefault` method instead.</del>

```
val pos = new HashMap[Int, Stack[Int]] withDefault (_ => Stack.empty[Int])
```

**Edit**

Above solution doesn't seem to work, I get empty stacks. Checking with sources shows that the default value is returned but never put into map

```
override def apply(key: A): B = {
  val result = findEntry(key)
  if (result eq null) default(key)
  else result.value
}
```

I guess one solution might be to override `apply` or `default` method to add the entry to map before returning it. Example for `default` method:

```
val pos = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Stack[Int]]() {
  override def default(key: Int) = {
    val newValue = mutable.Stack.empty[Int]
    this += key -> newValue
    newValue
  }
}
```

Btw. that is punishment for being mutable, I encourage you to use immutable data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more idiomatic Scala, functional-style solution without those mutable collections, consider this:

```
scala> val a = List(4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6)
a: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6)

scala> val pos = a.zipWithIndex groupBy {_._1} mapValues { _ map (_._2) }
pos: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(4 -> List(0, 3), 6 -> List(1, 2, 4, 5))
```

It may look confusing at first, but if you break it down, `zipWithIndex` gets pairs of values and their positions, `groupBy` makes a map from each value to a list of entries, and `mapValues` is then used to turn the lists of (value, position) pairs into just lists of positions.

```
scala> val pairs = a.zipWithIndex
pairs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((4,0), (6,1), (6,2), (4,3), (6,4), (6,5))

scala> val pairsByValue = pairs groupBy (_._1)
pairsByValue: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(4 -> List((4,0), (4,3)), 6 -> List((6,1), (6,2), (6,4), (6,5)))

scala> val pos = pairsByValue mapValues (_ map (_._2))
pos: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(4 -> List(0, 3), 6 -> List(1, 2, 4, 5))
```