# Scala: Iterate over mutable map of maps

Tags: scala

I have defined a mutable map of maps

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val default = Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
val count = Map.empty[Any, Map[String, Int]].withDefaultValue(default)
```

which I populate/update as in

```
count("furniture")("table") += 1
count("furniture")("chair") = 6
count("appliance")("dishwasher") = 1
```

How can I iterate over all items in `count`? And why does `count.keys` return an empty `Set()`?

Comment: You might want to check my answer regarding `withDefaultValue` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774362/scala-hash-of-stacks-has-only-one-stack-for-all-the-keys/34774883#34774883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default, does not create new Map when no value exists in collection, it just returns default value on such requests, and other changes are done on this default value.

```
count("furniture")("table") += 1
count("furniture")("chair") = 6
count("appliance")("dishwasher") = 1

count("banana") // will return Map with "table", "chair" & "dishwasher"
```

is equivalent

```
default("table") += 1
default("chair") = 6
default("dishwasher") = 1
```

And since you return this default value on any key, this default map will be returned on every call.

Your code will work like this.

```
count("furniture") = Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
count("appliance") = Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)

count("furniture")("table") += 1
count("furniture")("chair") = 6
count("appliance")("dishwasher") = 1
```

Comment: So would you know how a map that is instantiated with a *new* copy of the `default` map for any key can be created?

Comment: Also, why does `count.keys` return an empty `Set()`, while `count("furniture").keys` returns `Set(chair, table)` with the code I've posted in my question above?

Comment: In my code, key set returns list of all keys, and it works. In your case there are no keys, but a default value, which you modify, and count(Any) for anything will return this original default value, which you modified

Comment: You're right, `count("furniture")` returns the updated `default` map with all its entries. Would you think it would make sense to just check for the existence of a key before updating/inserting entries, and insert a copy (`default.clone()`) for any non-existing key?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach:

#### Issue #1:

```
val default = Map.empty[String,Int].withDefaultValue(0)
```

defines a value `default`. There is only one instance of this value and it can not be changed, since you defined as a `val`.

That means that your `count` map has a default value which is always the same instance of an empty map. Since `count` is empty, `count("furniture")` or `count("appliance")` is exactly the same as just `default`.

#### Issue #2:

`withDefaultValue` does not add entries to a map it just returns a default for undefined keys.

See @mavarazys answer

Comment: I don't think that «`count("furniture")` or `count("applicance")` is exactly the same as just `default`». The code in my question above actually returns `Map(chair -> 6, table -> 1)` for `count("furniture")`...

Comment: no it doesn't, i executed it and it returns `Map(dishwasher -> 1, chair -> 6, table -> 1)`

Comment: You're totally right, sorry for confusing things – and thanks for your help.